# NodeJs Amazon Api and aws

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I use the following library to work with the amazon product api, which is actually pretty cool
(-> `https://github.com/livelycode` ) but I'm stuck on a certain point.
I manage to retrieve a response, but somehow I'm searching in the wrong region

How can I set the api to the current region?
I'm already having a associate Id with EU region I guess, so I think I missed some config
Here's what I have:

```
var region = {
  host: "ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com", // use a different region to the default
};

var prodAdv = aws.createProdAdvClient('xxx', 
    'xxx', 'xxx-21',  region);

var options = {SearchIndex: "Books", Keywords: "Javascript"}

prodAdv.call("ItemSearch", options, function(err, result) {
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(result.Items.Item[0]));
    console.log(result.Items.Item[0]);

});
```

Currently it runs this service `http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01`, but I'd really like to change it to amazon.de

thank you

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might be interested in this later on.

I switched to https://github.com/dmcquay/node-apac and did just overwrite the defaultEndPoint

```
var util = require('util'),
    OperationHelper = require('apac').OperationHelper;

OperationHelper.defaultEndPoint = 'ecs.amazonaws.de'

var opHelper = new OperationHelper({
    awsId:     'xxx',
    awsSecret: 'xxx',
    assocId:   'xxx-'
});

opHelper.execute('ItemSearch', {
  'SearchIndex': 'Books',
  'Keywords': 'harry potter',
  'ResponseGroup': 'ItemAttributes,Offers'
}, function(results) {
    console.log(results.ItemSearchResponse.Items[0].Item);
});
```

I'm pretty sure, something like this is also possible in the other library.

Best

Answer (score 0):

just got the same problem.
My solution is the overriting the options while creating the

```
var prodAdvOptions = {host: "ecs.amazonaws.de", region: "DE"};
var prodAdv = aws.createProdAdvClient('yourAccessKeyId', 'yourSecretAccessKey', 'yourAssociateTag', prodAdvOptions );
```

with the prodAdvOptions  you can change the region and tne host.